# Apparent bug in pdflatex/xelatex (but not lualatex)

Tags: bugs

Steps to reproduce. Minimal LaTeX file `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\input{test.l2e}
\end{document}
```

file `test.l2e`:

```
\oops
```

run pdflatex or xelatex on test and hit `E` at the error prompt.

pdflatex says:

```
pdflatex:calledit: unexpected if_ptr=5 not in range 1..2,from input_stack[2].namefield=2378
```

xelatex says:

```
xelatex:calledit: unexpected if_ptr=6 not in range 1..2,from input_stack[2].namefield=2230090
```

lualatex calls the editor correctly.

Comment: would be better to raise on texk or texlive list I think. I have a feeliing I have seen this come up elsewhere. Interestingly if the top level file is just `\input test.l2e` and you use plain pdftex it opens the editor on e

Comment: What's odd is that I've had this work with other files being input in my book without problem... I thought perhaps it was the file extension but some fiddling showed I was still getting the error. ‍♂️ I'll have to join texk/texlive and raise the issue there. That's what happens when you take a 20-year break from the community.

Comment: I've run this under TeX Live 2021 isntalled by MacTeX and fully updated. When typesetting using pdflatex I get the expected error. This was using TeXShop as a front end.

Answer (score 2):

to simplify the test case a bit you can use plain tex and

```
\def\zz#1{#1}
\zz{\input test.l2e }
```

Note you need the wrapping macro, if you just call `\input` directly it works, presumably related to the `input_stack[2]` in the error when it fails.

Comment: https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2021-April/046845.html

Comment: @HironobuYAMASHITA aha I was sure I had seen that before but I searched the wrong list :-) thanks.